# Location.hash does not match history

Tags: javascript, iframe, history

I am experimenting with making a one page app with a header and an iframe for the content of the page. So... I made a little javaScript controller to do so. It takes an `enter code here`object named routes to handle clicks on some of the anchor tags which I want to trigger a change in the iFrames url. This is all working fine for me, but when I go to use the back button it does not seem to be aligned correctly.

this is where I got the idea: http://gtv-resources.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/location-hash-html.html#3

here is the article that google has written on it:  https://developers.google.com/tv/web/articles/location-hash-navigation

```
<script src="controller.js"></script>
    <script>
    var routes = {
        "view":"viewFrame",
        "index": {
            "name": "main",
            "location": "subpages/landing.html"
        },
        "paths": {
            "about": "subpages/about.html",
            "download": "subpages/download.html",
            "main":"subpages/landing.html"
        }
    };
    </script>

</head>



    <body>
         <ul>
            <li><a class='handle' data-link='main'>Back To Main Page</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class='handle' data-link='about'>About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class='handle' data-link='download'>Download</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <iframe id="viewFrame" src="subpages/landing.html">


    </body>
```

and my js file

```
window.onload = function() {

if (routes) {

    var View = routes,
        flag = true;

    View.update = function(hashValue, flag) {
        console.log('ok2')
        var frame = document.getElementById('viewFrame');

        frame.src = routes.paths[hashValue]
        if (flag) {
            View.setHash(hashValue);
        }

    };

    View.getHash = function() {
        return window.location.hash.substring(1);
    }


    View.setHash = function(str) {
        flag = false;
        window.location.hash = str;
    }


    window.onhashchange = function(e) {
        if (flag) {
            View.update(getLocationHash(), false);
        } else {
            flag = true;
        }
    };


    var hashValue = View.getHash(),
        handles = document.querySelectorAll('.handle');

    for (var i = 0; i < handles.length; i++) {
        console.log(handles[i]);
        handles[i].addEventListener('click', evTrigger)


    }

    function evTrigger() {
        console.log(this)
        var link = this.getAttribute('data-link')
        View.update(link, true)
    }

    if (hashValue == '') {
        View.update(routes.index.name, true);
    }
}
};
```

if you can interpret my madness I would be thankful for the help.

Comment: I did a little digging and found that changing the iframes src pushes an event to the history.  the solution was to replace the iframe every time i wanted to change its src.